# Make Notes like collapsing/staying sidebar

Tags: xcode, swiftui, appkit

In Apple's Notes App, you can drag the sidebar divider left/right and it will make the sidebar 'appear'/'disappear' based on it's width:

[image: Animated view of Notes sidebar getting dragged left/right]

How is this achievable? I'm quite new to OSX development and I might simply not have the right terminology to search for this.

Addendum: the apple docs provide info to the API, but is there a more visual docs or kitchen sink like app for learning the API? I've found the api to tell me options (i.e., compact, compactUnified, etc) but doesn't really show them.

Comment: is `.windowToolbarStyle` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply use `Navigation` to achieve this. Just copy the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sidebar View")
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 100)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                            .resizable()
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.grid.2x2")
                            .resizable()
                    }
                }
            Text("Main View")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

And add some code to your `XXXXXApp.swift` file:

```swift
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedCompactWindowToolbarStyle())
    .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem like it actually does what I was showing in the gif. It doesn't collapse with a divider but stays as a solid sidebar the entire time.